# Problems with string and charset using libconfig.h

Tags: c, struct, config, libconfig

I'm using `libconfig.h` to read parameters from a configuration file, but I've problems printing values inside/outside a function.

example.h

```
int get_config();
```

example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libconfig.h>
#include "example.h"

typedef struct Conf{
    int myInt;
    const char *myString;
}Conf;

#define CONFIGFILE "./my.conf"
Conf *config;


int get_config(){
    config_t cfg;
    config_init(&cfg);

    if (!config_read_file(&cfg, CONFIGFILE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d - %s\n",
            config_error_file(&cfg),
            config_error_line(&cfg),
            config_error_text(&cfg));
        config_destroy(&cfg);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(config_lookup_int(&cfg,"myInt", &config->myInt)){
        printf("myInt = %d\n", config->myInt);
    }

    if(config_lookup_string(&cfg,"myString", &config->myString)){
        printf("myString = %s\n", config->myString);
    }

    config_destroy(&cfg);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    config = (Conf*) malloc(sizeof(Conf));
    if(get_config() == EXIT_FAILURE){
        return 0;
    }
    get_config();

    printf("myInt = %d\n",config->myInt);
    printf("myString = %s\n",config->myString);

    return 0;
}
```

The value of `myInt` printed inside/outside `get_config()` is the same. For `myString`, the call in `main()` return spurious chars, different from what printed before.

What's wrong?

Comment: [In C you should not cast the result of `malloc`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

From the [libconfig manual](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html):

> Storage for the string returned by config_lookup_string() is managed by the library and released automatically when the setting is destroyed or when the setting's value is changed; the string must not be freed by the caller.

Your `config_t cfg` is local to `get_config` and goes out of scope after leaving that function. That means (a) that you can't clean up `cfg` properly with `config_destroy()` later and (b) that any references inside `cfg` might not be accessible, because the stack space has been overwritten.

You can make a copy of the string with `strdup` in `get_config`. In that case, destroy `cfg` at the end of `get_config`, just as you'd `fclose` any open local files. Also take care to `free` your string later.

Another approach is to make `cfg` local to `main` and keep it alive during the execution time of the program. Pass `&cfg` to `get_config` as a pointer and destroy `cfg` before returning from `main`. In that case, the string will be valid as long as `cfg` is valid.

Comment: Pardon me, I leave out the `config_destroy()` but it's not that the problem. Running it, I get values inside the function (Ok), but in main only the int value is right. The string show me spurious chars (eg. �e4).

Comment: My answer addresses this question: Your string, i.e. the memory needed to hold it, doesn't "stay alive" long enough. You either must make a copy (and don't care when the original string "dies") or make your `cfg`, which owns the original string, live long enough by making `cfg` a variable in `main`.

Comment: The string is stored as a pointer in `Conf`. When what it points to is no longer valid, the pointer is useless. That's what happens in your case. (Well, that's what _probably_ happens; I haven't tried it out, because I didn't want to install `libconfig`.) The `int` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Thank you! Now it run, leaving my string alive :) Is `libconfig` a good solution? something "better"?

Comment: I have no experience with `libconfig`, but from what I've seen it looks good to me. Better than rolling your own. The problem of pointers to char arrays going stale isn't a problem of `libconfig`, but of C. Be prepared to deal with it more often.